# How to configure log4net programmatically from scratch (no config)

Tags: .net, logging, log4net

This is a Bad Idea, I know, but...
I want to configure log4net programmatically from scratch with no config file. I'm working on a simple logging application for me and my team to use for a bunch of relatively small departmental applications we're responsible for. I want them to all log to the same database. The logging application is just a wrapper around log4net with the AdoNetAppender preconfigured.

All of the applications are ClickOnce deployed, which presents a small problem with deploying the config file. If the config file were part of the core project, I could set its properties to deploy with the assembly. But it's part of a linked application, so I don't have the option of deploying it with the main application. (If that's not true, somebody please let me know).

Probably because it's a Bad Idea, there doesn't seem to be much sample code available for programmatically configruating log4net from scratch. Here's what I have so far.

```
Dim apndr As New AdoNetAppender()
apndr.CommandText = "INSERT INTO LOG_ENTRY (LOG_DTM, LOG_LEVEL, LOGGER, MESSAGE, PROGRAM, USER_ID, MACHINE, EXCEPTION) VALUES (@log_date, @log_level, @logger, @message, @program, @user, @machine, @exception)"
apndr.ConnectionString = connectionString
apndr.ConnectionType = "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
apndr.CommandType = CommandType.Text
Dim logDate As New AdoNetAppenderParameter()
logDate.ParameterName = "@log_date"
logDate.DbType = DbType.DateTime
logDate.Layout = New RawTimeStampLayout()
apndr.AddParameter(logDate)
Dim logLevel As New AdoNetAppenderParameter()
logLevel.ParameterName = "@log_level"
'And so forth...
```

After configuring all the parameters for `apndr`, I at first tried this...

```
Dim hier As Hierarchy = DirectCast(LogManager.GetRepository(), Hierarchy)
hier.Root.AddAppender(apndr)
```

It didn't work. Then, as a shot in the dark, I tried this instead.

```
BasicConfigurator.Configure(apndr)
```

That didn't work either. Does anybody have any good references on how to configure log4net programmatically from scratch with no config file?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436713/cant-configure-log4net-in-code

Answer (score 38, accepted):

One way I've done this in the past is to include the configuration file as an embedded resource, and just used [log4net.Config.Configure(Stream)](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/M_log4net_Config_XmlConfigurator_Configure_7.htm).

That way, I could use the configuration syntax I was familiar with, and didn't have to worry about getting a file deployed.

Comment: The complete method name is log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure (as in the link)

Answer (score 125):

Here's an example class that creates log4net config completely in code.  I should mention that creating a logger via a static method is generally viewed as bad, but in my context, this is what I wanted.  Regardless, you can carve up the code to meet your needs.

```
using log4net;
using log4net.Repository.Hierarchy;
using log4net.Core;
using log4net.Appender;
using log4net.Layout;

namespace dnservices.logging
{
public class Logger
{
    private PatternLayout _layout = new PatternLayout();
    private const string LOG_PATTERN = "%d [%t] %-5p %m%n";

    public string DefaultPattern
    {
        get { return LOG_PATTERN; }
    }

    public Logger()
    {
        _layout.ConversionPattern = DefaultPattern;
        _layout.ActivateOptions();
    }

    public PatternLayout DefaultLayout
    {
        get { return _layout; }
    }

    public void AddAppender(IAppender appender)
    {
        Hierarchy hierarchy = 
            (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();

        hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(appender);
    }

    static Logger()
    {
        Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
        TraceAppender tracer = new TraceAppender();
        PatternLayout patternLayout = new PatternLayout();

        patternLayout.ConversionPattern = LOG_PATTERN;
        patternLayout.ActivateOptions();

        tracer.Layout = patternLayout;
        tracer.ActivateOptions();
        hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(tracer);

        RollingFileAppender roller = new RollingFileAppender();
        roller.Layout = patternLayout;
        roller.AppendToFile = true;
        roller.RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Size;
        roller.MaxSizeRollBackups = 4;
        roller.MaximumFileSize = "100KB";
        roller.StaticLogFileName = true;
        roller.File = "dnservices.txt";
        roller.ActivateOptions();
        hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(roller);

        hierarchy.Root.Level = Level.All;
        hierarchy.Configured = true;
    }

    public static ILog Create()
    {
        return LogManager.GetLogger("dnservices");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: +1 from me, it seems like you got the answer here of how to do this purely programmatically with no config file.

Comment: well, it still didn't work, empty text file is created, however nothing is written to it :(

Comment: @aloneguid Can you send me a small example where nothing is written to the log file?  My SO profile contains an email address.

Comment: +1 for `hierarchy.Configured = true;` which does the trick for me

Comment: The trick for me was roller.ActivateOptions()... Some dark Voodoo.

Comment: this seems buggy if you want multiple loggers. Like... can the appenders be tied to a specific logger?

Comment: What is "dnservices" ??? You retrieve it by name, but where did u set the name in the configuration???

Comment: This is very helpful if you want to merge different types of configurations into one type of configuration.

Comment: @Legends "dnsservices.txt" is just a relative name for your log file. Seems to be relative to the current working dir. I changed it to an absolute path on the user's system so the logs would always go to a known dir.

Answer (score 33):

More concise solution:

```
var layout = new PatternLayout("%-4timestamp [%thread] %-5level %logger %ndc - %message%newline");
var appender = new RollingFileAppender {
    File = "my.log",
    Layout = layout
};
layout.ActivateOptions();
appender.ActivateOptions();
BasicConfigurator.Configure(appender);
```

Don't forget to call [ActivateOptions](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/M_log4net_Appender_RollingFileAppender_ActivateOptions.htm) method:

> The ActivateOptions method must be called on this object after the configuration properties have been set. Until ActivateOptions is called this object is in an undefined state and must not be used.

Comment: Using the BasicConfigurator.Configure(IAppender) overload does save a lot of messing around, cheers.

Comment: +1 for that one. Calling `ActivateOptions()` is definitely missing or at least not pointed out enough in the docs.

Answer (score 5):

As [Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769983/how-to-configure-log4net-programmatically-from-scratch-no-config/770046#770046) says, using a resource is a good solution.

It's a bit restrictive in that the embedded resource contents will be fixed at compile time.  I have a logging component that generates an XmlDocument with a basic Log4Net configuration, using variables defined as appSettings (e.g. filename for a RollingFileAppender, default logging level, maybe connection string name if you want to use an AdoNetAppender).  And then I call `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure` to configure Log4Net using the root element of the generated XmlDocument.

Then administrators can customise the "standard" configuration by modifying a few appSettings (typically level, filename, ...) or can specify an external configuration file to get more control.

Answer (score 5):

A bit late for the party. But here is a minimal config that worked for me.

Sample class

```
public class Bar
{
    private readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Bar));
    public void DoBar() { log.Info("Logged"); }
}
```

Minimal log4net trace config (inside NUnit test)

```
[Test]
public void Foo()
{
    var tracer = new TraceAppender();
    var hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
    hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(tracer);
    var patternLayout = new PatternLayout {ConversionPattern = "%m%n"};
    tracer.Layout = patternLayout;
    hierarchy.Configured = true;

    var bar = new Bar();
    bar.DoBar();
}
```

Prints to the trace listener

```
Namespace+Bar: Logged
```

Comment: That almost works, but I needed to call .ActiveOptions on the PatternLayout and the Appender before it would fully work.

Comment: Not sure why. It worked for me as it is, maybe we used different versions.

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell in the question's code snippet if the "'And so forth..." includes the very important apndr.ActivateOptions() which is indicated in Todd Stout's answer.  Without ActivateOptions() the Appender is inactive and will not do anything which could explain why it is failing.

Comment: I don't think I had that in there. That may have been the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Dr. Netjes](http://weblogs.asp.net/drnetjes/archive/2005/02/16/374780.aspx) has this for setting the connectionstring programmatically:

```
// Get the Hierarchy object that organizes the loggers
log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy hier = 
  log4net.LogManager.GetLoggerRepository() as log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy;

if (hier != null)
{
  //get ADONetAppender
  log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender adoAppender = 
    (log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender)hier.GetLogger("MyProject",
      hier.LoggerFactory).GetAppender("ADONetAppender");
  if (adoAppender != null)
  {
    adoAppender.ConnectionString =
      System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["MyConnectionString"];
    adoAppender.ActivateOptions(); //refresh settings of appender
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

// I've embedded three config files as an Embedded Resource and access them like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Resources;
using System.IO;

namespace Loader
{
  class Program
  {
    private static log4net.ILog CustomerLog = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("CustomerLogging");
    private static log4net.ILog OrderLog = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("OrderLogging");
    private static log4net.ILog DetailsLog = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("OrderDetailLogging");


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      // array of embedded log4net config files
      string[] configs = { "Customer.config", "Order.config", "Detail.config"};

      foreach (var config in configs)
      {
        // build path to assembly config
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);
        sb.Append(".");
        sb.Append(config);

        // convert to a stream
        Stream configStream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(sb.ToString());

        // configure logger with ocnfig stream
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(configStream);

        // test logging
        CustomerLog.Info("Begin logging with: " + config);
        OrderLog.Info("Begin logging with: " + config);
        DetailsLog.Info("Begin logging with: " + config);
        for (int iX = 0; iX < 10; iX++)
        {
          CustomerLog.Info("iX=" + iX);
          OrderLog.Info("iX=" + iX);
          DetailsLog.Info("iX=" + iX);
        }
        CustomerLog.Info("Ending logging with: " + config);
        OrderLog.Info("Ending logging with: " + config);
        DetailsLog.Info("Ending logging with: " + config);
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is strange that `BasicConfigurator.Configure(apndr)` did not work. In my case it did its job... But, anyway, here goes the answer - you should've wrote `hier.Configured = true;` (c# code) after you've finished all setup.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this:

http://www.mikebevers.be/blog/2010/09/log4net-custom-adonetappender/

After 4 hours fiddling with the config and getting progressively more frustrated.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a soup-to-nuts example of how you can create and use an `AdoNetAdapter` entirely in code, completely in the absence of any `App.config` file (not even for `Common.Logging`). Go ahead, delete it!

This has the added benefit of being resilient against updates under the [new naming conventions](https://github.com/net-commons/common-logging/wiki/Common.Logging-Packaging-and-Versions), where the assembly name now reflects the version. (`Common.Logging.Log4Net1213`, etc.)

[SQL]

```
CREATE TABLE [Log](
  [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
  [Thread] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
  [Level] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
  [Source] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
  [Message] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
  [Exception] [varchar](max) NOT NULL
)
```

[Main]

```
Imports log4net
Imports log4net.Core
Imports log4net.Layout
Imports log4net.Config
Imports log4net.Appender

Module Main
  Sub Main()
    Dim oLogger As ILog
    Dim sInput As String
    Dim iOops As Integer

    BasicConfigurator.Configure(New DbAppender)
    oLogger = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType(Main))

    Console.Write("Command: ")

    Do
      Try
        sInput = Console.ReadLine.Trim

        Select Case sInput.ToUpper
          Case "QUIT" : Exit Do
          Case "OOPS" : iOops = String.Empty
          Case Else : oLogger.Info(sInput)
        End Select

      Catch ex As Exception
        oLogger.Error(ex.Message, ex)

      End Try

      Console.Clear()
      Console.Write("Command: ")
    Loop
  End Sub
End Module
```

[DbAppender]

```
Imports log4net
Imports log4net.Core
Imports log4net.Layout
Imports log4net.Appender
Imports log4net.Repository.Hierarchy

Public Class DbAppender
  Inherits AdoNetAppender

  Public Sub New()
    MyBase.BufferSize = 1
    MyBase.CommandText = Me.CommandText

    Me.Parameters.ForEach(Sub(Parameter As DbParameter)
                            MyBase.AddParameter(Parameter)
                          End Sub)

    Me.ActivateOptions()
  End Sub



  Protected Overrides Function CreateConnection(ConnectionType As Type, ConnectionString As String) As IDbConnection
    Return MyBase.CreateConnection(GetType(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection), "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Logger;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Password=password")
  End Function



  Private Overloads ReadOnly Property CommandText As String
    Get
      Dim _
        sColumns,
        sValues As String

      sColumns = Join(Me.Parameters.Select(Function(P As DbParameter) P.DbColumn).ToArray, ",")
      sValues = Join(Me.Parameters.Select(Function(P As DbParameter) P.ParameterName).ToArray, ",")

      Return String.Format(COMMAND_TEXT, sColumns, sValues)
    End Get
  End Property



  Private ReadOnly Property Parameters As List(Of DbParameter)
    Get
      Parameters = New List(Of DbParameter)
      Parameters.Add(Me.LogDate)
      Parameters.Add(Me.Thread)
      Parameters.Add(Me.Level)
      Parameters.Add(Me.Source)
      Parameters.Add(Me.Message)
      Parameters.Add(Me.Exception)
    End Get
  End Property



  Private ReadOnly Property LogDate As DbParameter
    Get
      Return New DbParameter("Date", DbType.Date, 0, New DbPatternLayout("%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}"))
    End Get
  End Property



  Private ReadOnly Property Thread As DbParameter
    Get
      Return New DbParameter("Thread", DbType.String, 255, New DbPatternLayout("%thread"))
    End Get
  End Property



  Private ReadOnly Property Level As DbParameter
    Get
      Return New DbParameter("Level", DbType.String, 50, New DbPatternLayout("%level"))
    End Get
  End Property



  Private ReadOnly Property Source As DbParameter
    Get
      Return New DbParameter("Source", DbType.String, 255, New DbPatternLayout("%logger.%M()"))
    End Get
  End Property



  Private ReadOnly Property Message As DbParameter
    Get
      Return New DbParameter("Message", DbType.String, 4000, New DbPatternLayout("%message"))
    End Get
  End Property



  Private ReadOnly Property Exception As DbParameter
    Get
      Return New DbParameter("Exception", DbType.String, 2000, New DbExceptionLayout)
    End Get
  End Property



  Private Const COMMAND_TEXT As String = "INSERT INTO Log ({0}) VALUES ({1})"
End Class
```

[DbParameter]

```
Imports log4net
Imports log4net.Core
Imports log4net.Layout
Imports log4net.Appender
Imports log4net.Repository.Hierarchy

Public Class DbParameter
  Inherits AdoNetAppenderParameter

  Private ReadOnly Name As String

  Public Sub New(Name As String, Type As DbType, Size As Integer, Layout As ILayout)
    With New RawLayoutConverter
      Me.Layout = .ConvertFrom(Layout)
    End With

    Me.Name = Name.Replace("@", String.Empty)
    Me.ParameterName = String.Format("@{0}", Me.Name)
    Me.DbType = Type
    Me.Size = Size
  End Sub



  Public ReadOnly Property DbColumn As String
    Get
      Return String.Format("[{0}]", Me.Name)
    End Get
  End Property
End Class
```

[DbPatternLayout]

```
Imports log4net
Imports log4net.Core
Imports log4net.Layout
Imports log4net.Appender
Imports log4net.Repository.Hierarchy

Public Class DbPatternLayout
  Inherits PatternLayout

  Public Sub New(Pattern As String)
    Me.ConversionPattern = Pattern
    Me.ActivateOptions()
  End Sub
End Class
```

[DbExceptionLayout]

```
Imports log4net
Imports log4net.Core
Imports log4net.Layout
Imports log4net.Appender
Imports log4net.Repository.Hierarchy

Public Class DbExceptionLayout
  Inherits ExceptionLayout

  Public Sub New()
    Me.ActivateOptions()
  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

'Solution for Vb.Net

```
Private Shared EscanerLog As log4net.ILog = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("Log4Net.Config")

Public Sub New(ByVal sIDSesion As String)
    Dim sStream As Stream
    Dim JsText As String
    Using reader As New StreamReader((GetType(ClsGestorLogsTraza).Assembly).GetManifestResourceStream("Comun.Log4Net.Config"))
        JsText = reader.ReadToEnd()
        sStream = GenerateStreamFromString(JsText)
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(sStream)
    End Using
End Sub

Public Function GenerateStreamFromString(ByVal s As String) As Stream
    Dim stream = New MemoryStream()
    Dim writer = New StreamWriter(stream)
    writer.Write(s)
    writer.Flush()
    stream.Position = 0
    Return stream
End Function

Public Function StreamFromResource(ByVal sFilename As String) As Stream
    Dim nAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    Dim s As Stream = nAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.DeclaringType, sFilename)
    Return s
End Function
```