# Enable file logging for log4net from code instead of from configuration

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

Why in the world does the following test fail? (its in xunit)  I've tried it with different appenders and it never writes anything though the log seems like it is ready to write.  I eventually created my own appender just to test it.

```
    public class TestAppender : AppenderSkeleton {
        public event Action<LoggingEvent> AppendCalled = delegate { };
        protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent) {
            AppendCalled(loggingEvent);
        }
    }
    public class Class1 {
        private TestAppender _appender = new TestAppender();
        public Class1() {
            log4net.Util.LogLog.InternalDebugging = true;
            Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
            Logger rootLogger = hierarchy.Root;
            rootLogger.Level = Level.All;
            Logger coreLogger = hierarchy.GetLogger("abc") as Logger;
            coreLogger.Level = Level.All;

            coreLogger.Parent = rootLogger;
            PatternLayout patternLayout = new PatternLayout();
            patternLayout.ConversionPattern = "%logger - %message %newline";
            patternLayout.ActivateOptions();
            _appender.Layout = patternLayout;
            _appender.ActivateOptions();
            coreLogger.AddAppender(_appender);            
        }
        [Fact]
        public void Test() {
            bool called = false;
            _appender.AppendCalled += e => called = true;
            var log = LogManager.GetLogger("abc");
            log.Debug("This is a debugging message");
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            log.Info("This is an info message");
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            log.Warn("This is a warning message");
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            log.Error("This is an error message");
            Assert.True(called);
        }
}
```

Comment: What info do you get in the test? Or does it just appear nothing is called?

Comment: Append is never called - no idea why.  log4net configuration is still a bit of a black box to me even after using it on several projects.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I always use the code below to configure log4net from code. Works great!

```
Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
hierarchy.Root.RemoveAllAppenders(); /*Remove any other appenders*/

FileAppender fileAppender = new FileAppender();
fileAppender.AppendToFile = true;
fileAppender.LockingModel = new FileAppender.MinimalLock();
fileAppender.File = Server.MapPath("/") + "log.txt";
PatternLayout pl = new PatternLayout();
pl.ConversionPattern = "%d [%2%t] %-5p [%-10c]   %m%n%n";
pl.ActivateOptions();
fileAppender.Layout = pl;
fileAppender.ActivateOptions();

log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(fileAppender);

//Test logger
ILog log =LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
log.Debug("Testing!");
```

Comment: wow thanks, I never knew about the BasicConfigurator.Configure step

Comment: I know this is an old post but do you need to do any xml configuration in the web.config?

Answer (score 2):

Just throwing a guess out there...

Do you have the XmlConfiguration defined in your assembly?

Did you forget it in your test project?

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

That usually burns me every once in a while.

Comment: Good call I usually use log4net castle windsor integration so I forgot - but I'm not using an xml file at all!

Answer (score 0):

Still can't say why the above code doesn't work but I got log4net to configure properly and use my appender by replacing all the configuration code with:

```
log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(_appender);
```

From [here](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/06/16/log4net.html?page=3).