# Azure web job and log4net

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I am using Azure web jobs to schedule certain tasks.
The web job get deploy successfully in an Azure web app, but I am not able to relatively determine the path to the app_data folder where to log files should be stored. (web job is located in d:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\jobs\triggered\webjobname)

The following (absolute) path works:

```
<file value="d:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\App_Data\\Logs\\WebJobLog.txt" />
```

The following paths do not work:

```
<file value="../../App_Data/Logs/WebJobLog.txt" />
<file value="/App_Data/Logs/WebJobLog.txt" />
<file value="~/App_Data/Logs/WebJobLog.txt" />
```

Anyone knows how to set the file path relatively?

Comment: why bother, its not like this path is going to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you could specify your path as follows to achieve your purpose:

```
<file value="App_Data\\Logs\\WebJobLog.log" />
```

While for WebJobs, your webjob would be copied to a temp directory (e.g. `%TEMP%\jobs\{job type}\{job name}\{random name}`) by default for running, at this point your log file would under the temp folder. For more details, you could refer to [WebJob Working Directory](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs).

Based on your requirement, you could leverage [log4net.Util.PatternString](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/?topic=html/T_log4net_Util_PatternString.htm) and use the `env` conversion pattern to retrieve the environment variable (`WEBROOT_PATH`) suggested by David Ebbo. You need to change your path as follows:

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%env{WEBROOT_PATH}\\App_Data\\Logs\\WebJobLog.log" />
```

Additionally, you could create your `FileAppender` programmatically, for this approach you could refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436713/enable-file-logging-for-log4net-from-code-instead-of-from-configuration). Moreover, you could check the build-in logging for webjobs [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs#logging).

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid hard coding relative assumptions about where the WebJobs is deployed.

If your goal is to get to the `APP_DATA` folder, you can look at the `WEBROOT_PATH` environment variable, which points to `d:\home\site\wwwroot`, and then combine it with `APP_DATA`.