# Log4net: separate log files for each class

Tags: log4net

i want to log messages from multiple classes. the problem is that currently i can log all messages into single file.i want to do this class A should log its messages into ALog.txt and class B should log its messages into BLog.txt

please tell me the sample config file for these settings

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In addition to the `root` logger, you can configure individual loggers with their own appenders. Assuming you are calling your loggers `ClassA` and `ClassB` you can do:

```
<root>
     <appender-ref ref="CommonAppender" />
</root>
<logger name="ClassA">
     <appender-ref ref="AppenderA" />
</logger>
<logger name="ClassB">
     <appender-ref ref="AppenderB" />
</logger>
```

This is further described [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html).

Comment: Can we achieve this programmatically? Since I will be taking the name of the log file from user for each class. Can I set FileAppender and its attributes through code?

Comment: @dhirajsuvarna - indeed. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1776025/35245