# Use current class name as name for log folder in log4net

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net

I've created a scheduler project (console application with quartz.net) that contains several classes (jobs) that will be executed recurrently. I'm using log4Net to create the log files and right now every job is appending it's messages to the same file called scheduler/Scheduler.Info.txt. I would like to have a differente folder for each scheduler job.

what I have now is every job appending on

```
scheduler/scheduler/scheduler.Info.txt
```

what I want is:

```
scheduler/SomeJob1/SomeJobJob1.Info.txt
scheduler/SomeJob2/SomeJobJob2.Info.txt
scheduler/SomeJob3/SomeJobJob3.Info.txt
```

So, the pattern is

```
scheduler/{CLASS NAME}/{CLASS NAME}.Info.txt
```

My current configuration for log4net:

```
<log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="SchedulerLogFileInfoAppender" />
    </root>

    <appender name="SchedulerLogFileInfoAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
      <param name="File" value="c:\Scheduler\Scheduler.Info.log" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />

      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss} - %p - %logger - %m%n" />
      </layout>

      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMax value="INFO" />
      </filter>
    </appender>
</log4net>
```

And this is one of the jobs logging a message:

```
 public class SomeJob1: IJob
    {
        private static readonly ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    ...

     private void DoStuff()
     {
         logger.Info("THIS IS A MESSAGE");

         ...
     }
}
```

Comment: So just to clarify, these are not 3 **named instances** of `SomeJob`, but actually 3 instances of 3 classes, `SomeJob1, SomeJob2, SomeJob3`?

Comment: If that is the case, then an answer was already posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445642/log4net-separate-log-files-for-each-class

Comment: Yes, but I was hoping there was a 'dynamic' way to do it since we plan to add a lot more jobs to this scheduler