# How to configure NHibernate logging with log4net in code, not in xml file?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, configuration, log4net, app-config

Relying on this doc http://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/various/configure-log4net-for-use-with-nhibernate.html it is quite easy to configure NHibernate logging through log4net by using XML config files.

But i need to do the same in C# code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is based on [How to configure log4net programmatically from scratch (no config)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1776025/634872). However, since that answer only provides a solution for the root logger, I expanded that a little.

```
/// <summary>
/// Test for Log4Net
/// </summary>
public static void TestLog4Net()
{
    // Configures log4net
    ConfigureLog4net();
    ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("foo");
    log.Debug("This should not appear in a logfile!");

    ILog log2 = LogManager.GetLogger("NHibernate.SQL");
    log2.Debug("This should only appear in the NH logfile!");

    ILog log3 = LogManager.GetLogger("MyProgram");
    log3.Debug("This should appear in the main program logfile!");
}

/// <summary>
/// Configures log4net
/// </summary>
public static void ConfigureLog4net()
{
    Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
    // Remove any other appenders
    hierarchy.Root.RemoveAllAppenders();
    // define some basic settings for the root
    Logger rootLogger = hierarchy.Root;
    rootLogger.Level = Level.Debug;

    // declare a RollingFileAppender with 5MB per file and max. 10 files
    RollingFileAppender appenderNH = new RollingFileAppender();
    appenderNH.Name = "RollingLogFileAppenderNHibernate";
    appenderNH.AppendToFile = true;
    appenderNH.MaximumFileSize = "5MB";
    appenderNH.MaxSizeRollBackups = 10;
    appenderNH.RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Size;
    appenderNH.StaticLogFileName = true;
    appenderNH.LockingModel = new FileAppender.MinimalLock();
    appenderNH.File = "log-nhibernate.log";
    appenderNH.Layout = new PatternLayout("%date - %message%newline");
    // this activates the FileAppender (without it, nothing would be written)
    appenderNH.ActivateOptions();

    // This is required, so that we can access the Logger by using 
    // LogManager.GetLogger("NHibernate.SQL") and it can used by NHibernate
    Logger loggerNH = hierarchy.GetLogger("NHibernate.SQL") as Logger;
    loggerNH.Level = Level.Debug;
    loggerNH.AddAppender(appenderNH);

    // declare RollingFileAppender with 5MB per file and max. 10 files
    RollingFileAppender appenderMain = new RollingFileAppender();
    appenderMain.Name = "RollingLogFileAppenderMyProgram";
    appenderMain.AppendToFile = true;
    appenderMain.MaximumFileSize = "5MB";
    appenderMain.MaxSizeRollBackups = 10;
    appenderMain.RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Size;
    appenderMain.StaticLogFileName = true;
    appenderMain.LockingModel = new FileAppender.MinimalLock();
    appenderMain.File = "log-MyProgram.log";
    appenderMain.Layout = new PatternLayout(
        "%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] - %message%newline");
    // this activates the FileAppender (without it, nothing would be written)
    appenderMain.ActivateOptions();

    // This is required, so that we can access the Logger by using 
    // LogManager.GetLogger("MyProgram") 
    Logger logger = hierarchy.GetLogger("MyProgram") as Logger;
    logger.Level = Level.Debug;
    logger.AddAppender(appenderMain);

    // this is required to tell log4net that we're done 
    // with the configuration, so the logging can start
    hierarchy.Configured = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find information about configuring log4net programatically [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4net-user/200602.mbox/%3CDDEB64C8619AC64DBC074208B046611C769745@kronos.neoworks.co.uk%3E) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1776025/106567). You are going to need a direct reference to the log4net assembly in your project and then you write the necessary code so that it is executed on application start-up (as early as possible).

The question however is why would you want to do this...