# Windsor Logging Facility with Custom Log4Net configuration

Tags: castle-windsor, windsor-facilities

I have the windsor logging facility working on my project by following this page: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Logging-Facility.ashx and then using a log4net.config.

However I am interested in not using the log4net.config but in using the code based appender setup as detailed in this post: [How to configure log4net programmatically from scratch (no config)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769983/how-to-configure-log4net-programmatically-from-scratch-no-config)

Is this possible with the logging facility?  What is the best way to perform this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `ILoggerFactory` then pass the type to the logging facility with the `LogUsing<T>` method. (the type parameter is your logger factory).