# Using log4net in c# without xml files

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services, log4net

I want to use log4net for my windows service application to write logs but without using xml.
A piece of code would help. Thank You

Comment: Do you mean without writing the logs to XML or without using XML configuration files?

Comment: without using xml configration files.

Comment: @user1467270: Then see below. Two answers, actually. May you choose the best one :).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure log4net programmatically from scratch (no config)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769983/how-to-configure-log4net-programmatically-from-scratch-no-config)

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean that you do not want an external configuration file for log4net, but you want it embedded in your app.config or web.config.

Configuring it from code is not a good idea. You often need to maintain that configuration, change file location, change log size, etc. So you need an easily accessible location to do it.

[Here's](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11328/Configure-Log4Net-for-Desktop-and-Web-Applications) an article that shows you how to embed the log4net configuration in your application configuration file.

Comment: So in any case i have to write configuration file. for good programming practise you mean?

Comment: @user1467270: Indeed. You don't have to look at it as a heavy task. You write it once and that's it. You maybe will modify it from time to time with extra settings. But nothing to add too much overhead. And yes, configuration files are a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure `log4net` to use whatever type of appender you like, not just `XML`.  [See here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.html) for many different kinds of appenders.

You can configure it in your `Web.config` (or `App.config`) like this, for example:

```
<log4net>  
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender, log4net">
      <param name="File" value="Log\Log.NHibernate.txt" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="false" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout, log4net">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <!-- Note: Priority level can be ALL/DEBUG/INFO/WARN/ERROR/FATAL/OFF -->
    <root>
      <priority value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Comment: i don't want to use any configuration files. just simply create logs without any configuration file.