# log4net RollingFileAppender takes no variables for Parameters: maxSizeRollBackups, maxFileSize or maximumFileSize

Tags: c#, log4net

**This code works as expected** in Log4net: `<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value=".\\somefolder\\myLog.%property{logId}.log"/>`

Adding thie following C# code the **logfile "myLog.2.log" is created** successfully

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["logId"] = 2;
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(log4NetConfigFilePath));
```

### **Here comes the problem:**

Using Variables like maxSizeRollBackups, maxFileSize or maximumFileSize for RollingFileAppender doesn't work for me. **Depending on the Property different errors occur:**

**1) maximumFileSize :**

C#

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["maxfilesize"] = 15;
```

log4net.config:

```
<maximumFileSize value="%property{maxfilesize}MB" />
```

I get the error:

> log4net:ERROR OptionConverter: [%PROPERTY{MAXFILESIZE}] is not in the
>   correct file size syntax.

**2) maxSizeRollBackups:**

C#:

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["maxrollbackups"] = 5;
```

Log4net.config:

```
<maxSizeRollBackups value="%property{maxrollbackups}" />
```

I get the error:

> log4net:ERROR Could not create Appender [RollingLogFileAppender] of
>   type [dotnet.CustomFileAppender]. Reported error follows.
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.FormatException: Input
>   string was not in a correct format.    at
>   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options,
>   NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style,
>   NumberFormatInfo info)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at log4net.Util.OptionConverter.ConvertStringTo(Type target, String
>   txt)    at
>   log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.ConvertStringTo(Type
>   type, String value)    at
>   log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.SetParameter(XmlElement
>   element, Object target)    at
>   log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.ParseAppender(XmlElement
>   appenderElement) log4net:ERROR Appender named [RollingLogFileAppender]
>   not found.

Additional Info:

- The **RollingFileAppender works fine as long as I use fixed values in the config.**
- For the maxFileSize property also the 2) error occurs.
- Using both Properties maxSizeRollBackups & maximumFileSize with variables at the same time, ends up in the second error
- [Docu regarding MaximumFileSize vs MaxFileSize](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.MaximumFileSize.html)

Comment: There is an example of setting these limits here, it seems http://stackoverflow.com/a/1776025/242520