# How to intercept and replace Quartz.NET's default logging at runtime?

Tags: log4net, quartz.net

In order to eliminate human error and avoid the tedium of maintaining who-knows-how-many `App.config` files, I've decided to set all of my Quartz.NET jobs' Log4Net configurations at runtime, completely in code. No `App.config` files allowed. I've been successful in getting a standalone console app to do this, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28656694/722393).

However, it's a different story in the scheduler itself. For some reason it's not using the configuration that I'm specifying:

```
Dim oProperties As New NameValueCollection

' ... Set Quartz.NET properties here

BasicConfigurator.Configure(New Logger.DbAppender)

With New StdSchedulerFactory(oProperties)
  Manager.Scheduler = .GetScheduler
End With
```

I'm running it as a TopShelf service and I'd like the `Scheduler`'s logs to go to the same destination as each of the `IJob`s. Here, Quartz.NET stubbornly continues to send its output to TopShelf's debugging console window (STDOUT).

This construct works in the console app (linked above); why isn't it working here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, got it. (For REAL this time.)

Clarification: the suppression of logging in the absence of a `.config` file occurs in `Common.Logging` when run under the TopShelf/Quartz.NET combination. For some reason it consistently refuses to recognize a runtime-loaded `Appender`, even when the first line of code in the service configures logging. Still a mystery, but not important. (At least not for me, with this latest discovery—YMMV.)

The only logging that's suppressed is that which follows the buildup and teardown of the `Common.Logging` library itself; everything that occurs in the service itself is still logged.

I was able to get it to work using the code below (in combination with the code linked to above, of course).

As I said, YMMV.

[Service]

```
Public Module Main
  Sub Main()
    Try
      BasicConfigurator.Configure(New Logger.DbAppender("ConnectionString"))
      Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType(Main))

      Environment.ExitCode = HostFactory.Run(Sub(Configurator)
                                               Configurator.Service(Of Manager)(Sub(Service)
                                                                                  Service.ConstructUsing(Function(Factory) As ServiceControl
                                                                                                           Return New Manager
                                                                                                         End Function)

                                                                                  Service.WhenStarted(Function(Manager, HostControl) As Boolean
                                                                                                        Return Manager.StartService(HostControl)
                                                                                                      End Function)

                                                                                  Service.WhenStopped(Function(Manager, HostControl) As Boolean
                                                                                                        Return Manager.StopService(HostControl)
                                                                                                      End Function)
                                                                                End Sub)

                                               Configurator.SetDescription(ServiceInfo.Description)
                                               Configurator.SetServiceName(ServiceInfo.Product)
                                               Configurator.SetDisplayName(ServiceInfo.Title)
                                               Configurator.StartAutomatically()
                                               Configurator.RunAsLocalSystem()
                                             End Sub)

    Catch ex As Exception
      EventLog.WriteEntry(ServiceInfo.Product, ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error, 1, 1, ex.ToBytes)

    End Try
  End Sub



  Public Property Logger As ILog
End Module
```

[DbAppender] (updated w/add'l constructor that accepts a connection string)

```
Public Class DbAppender
  Inherits AdoNetAppender

  Public Sub New()
    Me.New(String.Empty)
  End Sub



  Public Sub New(ConnectionString As String)
    If Trim(ConnectionString) <> String.Empty Then
      MyBase.ConnectionString = ConnectionString
    End If

    MyBase.CommandText = Me.CommandText
    MyBase.BufferSize = 1

    Me.Parameters.ForEach(Sub(Parameter As DbParameter)
                            MyBase.AddParameter(Parameter)
                          End Sub)

    Me.ActivateOptions()
  End Sub



  Protected Overrides Function CreateConnection(ConnectionType As Type, ConnectionString As String) As IDbConnection
    Return MyBase.CreateConnection(GetType(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection), MyBase.ConnectionString)
  End Function



  Private Overloads ReadOnly Property CommandText As String
    Get
      Dim _
        sColumns,
        sValues As String

      sColumns = Join(Me.Parameters.Select(Function(P As DbParameter) P.DbColumn).ToArray, ",")
      sValues = Join(Me.Parameters.Select(Function(P As DbParameter) P.ParameterName).ToArray, ",")

      Return COMMAND_TEXT.ToFormat(sColumns, sValues)
    End Get
  End Property



  Private ReadOnly Property Parameters As List(Of DbParameter)
    Get
      Parameters = New List(Of DbParameter)
      Parameters.Add(Me.Date)
      Parameters.Add(Me.Thread)
      Parameters.Add(Me.Level)
      Parameters.Add(Me.Source)
      Parameters.Add(Me.Message)
      Parameters.Add(Me.Exception)
    End Get
  End Property



  Private ReadOnly Property [Date] As DbParameter
    Get
      Return New DbParameter("Date", New DbPatternLayout(PATTERN_DATE), DbType.Date, 0)
    End Get
  End Property



  Private ReadOnly Property Thread As DbParameter
    Get
      Return New DbParameter("Thread", New DbPatternLayout(PATTERN_THREAD), DbType.String, 255)
    End Get
  End Property



  Private ReadOnly Property Level As DbParameter
    Get
      Return New DbParameter("Level", New DbPatternLayout(PATTERN_LEVEL), DbType.String, 50)
    End Get
  End Property



  Private ReadOnly Property Source As DbParameter
    Get
      Return New DbParameter("Source", New DbPatternLayout(PATTERN_SOURCE), DbType.String, 255)
    End Get
  End Property



  Private ReadOnly Property Message As DbParameter
    Get
      Return New DbParameter("Message", New DbPatternLayout(PATTERN_MESSAGE), DbType.String, 4000)
    End Get
  End Property



  Private ReadOnly Property Exception As DbParameter
    Get
      Return New DbParameter("Exception", New DbExceptionLayout)
    End Get
  End Property



  Private Const PATTERN_MESSAGE As String = "%message"
  Private Const PATTERN_THREAD As String = "%thread"
  Private Const PATTERN_SOURCE As String = "%logger.%M()"
  Private Const PATTERN_LEVEL As String = "%level"
  Private Const PATTERN_DATE As String = "%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}"
  Private Const COMMAND_TEXT As String = "INSERT INTO Log ({0}) VALUES ({1})"
  '======================================================================================
  ' Available patterns:
  ' http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html
  '======================================================================================
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, got it. (That didn't take long!)

For some reason, the TopShelf/Quartz.NET combo insists on suppressing logging output if the requisite `App.config` entries are missing.

In this case, since it's the central scheduler we're dealing with and not a plethora of jobs, I'll bite the bullet and go ahead and use an `App.config` file for this one.

So the root problem remains unsolved; this is just a workaround for the time being. If you know the answer I'd still be pleased to hear from you. Thanks.