# Define log4net file appender DatePattern property programatically

Tags: c#, log4net, rollingfileappender

I try to instantiate a log4net rollingfile appender programmatically like this:

```
private void GetFileAppender(string appenderName)
{
    // Get the logger repository hierarchy.  
    Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();

    /// Set the pattern layout for this appender
    PatternLayout patternLayout = new PatternLayout();
    patternLayout.ConversionPattern = "%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline";
    patternLayout.ActivateOptions();

    /// Instantiate a new file appender
    this._fileAppender = new RollingFileAppender();
    this._fileAppender.Name = appenderName + "FileAppender";
    this._fileAppender.AppendToFile = true;
    this._fileAppender.Layout = patternLayout;
    this._fileAppender.File = "C:\\LogTest_";
    this._fileAppender.StaticLogFileName = false;
    this._fileAppender.DatePattern = "dd.MM.yyyy_hh'.log'";
    this._fileAppender.RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Size;
    this._fileAppender.MaximumFileSize = "10MB";
    this._fileAppender.MaxSizeRollBackups = 10;

    /// Define filter for this appender
    LevelRangeFilter levelRangeFilter = new LevelRangeFilter { LevelMin = Level.Debug, LevelMax = Level.Fatal, AcceptOnMatch = true };
    DenyAllFilter denyAllFilter = new log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter();
    this._fileAppender.AddFilter(levelRangeFilter);
    this._fileAppender.AddFilter(denyAllFilter);
    this._fileAppender.ActivateOptions();
    hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(this._fileAppender);
    hierarchy.Root.Level = Level.Debug;
    hierarchy.Configured = true;
}
```

The logging itself works fine. The only problem i have is that the pattern for the file name doesnt work.
I dont get the DateTime pattern and file extension for the log file defined by the DatePattern property.
I just get the "LogTest_" as file name without the dateTime and extension.

How can this be solved? It forks if i configure it via XAML in my App.config. But i want to solve this programmatically.

**SOLVED:**
The problem was that i had to set the RollingStyle to **Composite**

```
this._fileAppender.RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Composite;
```

By doing that it takes the patter defined by the property DatePattern.

Answer (score 0):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1776025/1137586).

In `RollingFileAppender`, you have `DatePattern` property:

```
RollingFileAppender roller = new RollingFileAppender();
        roller.DatePattern = "yyyy.MM.dd";;
```

Comment: If you would have read my entire post you could see that the DatePattern property was set.